# converting a utc format date string to date object in Extjs

Tags: date, extjs, internet-explorer-8, utc

I have a date string in the format "2013-01-31T10:10:05.000Z". I want to convert this string to a Date object in extjs.

I have tried to use Ext.Date.parse("2013-01-31T10:10:05.000Z","Y-m-dTH:i:s.uZ"). But it is returning undefined.

I also tried with new Date("2013-01-31T10:10:05.000Z"), but it is also returning undefined.

Note: I have tried in IE8 browser.

Could anyone please help me to convert the above date string to Date object?

Thanks a lot sra. Now I am getting the result as ...UTC+5:30... Is there any way to convert this in IST format?

Comment: ok. Thanks for providing this information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `Ext.Date.parse("2013-01-31T10:10:05.000Z","c");`

The `c` is the format type for *ISO 8601* formatted dates

See the **[Ext.Date API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Date)** for more details on this or other available formats

Comment: Can I know what is "c" in the line Ext.Date.parse("2013-01-31T10:10:05.000Z","c");?

Answer (score 0):

That's because 'T' and 'Z' are special characters in the Date format: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Date

You have to escape them like this: `Ext.Date.parse("2013-01-31T10:10:05.000Z","Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.u\\Z")`